# Fontawesome icons inside a button prevents value

Tags: php, css, html

I am using a button element for posting data. If the button contains a fontawesome icon it doesn't send the value attribute but the text.

```
<button name="foo" value="bar" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
```

Posts "foo" => ""

```
<button name="foo" value="bar" type="submit">dummy<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
```

Posts "foo" => "dummy"

```
<button name="foo" value="bar" type="submit">dummy</button>
```

Posts "foo" => "bar"

I tried both Chrome and Firefox with same results. What is the conventional way to include a fontawesome icon in a button and pass it's value attribute rather than text.

Accoarding to W3C only Internet Explorer 8 should have this behavior.
Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me. 
Here's my code:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' />

<form method='post' action='/del.php'>
    <input type='text' name='input-name' />
    <button name='button-name' type='submit' value='button-value'><i class='fa fa-twitter'></i></button>
</form>


<?php var_dump($_POST) ?>
```

and here's the output:

```
array(2) { ["input-name"]=> string(4) "meow" ["button-name"]=> string(12) "button-value" }
```

Perhaps you just forgot to close your button tag or your i tag.

Comment: I'm going nuts over this. My real code is <button class="red" type="submit" name="remove" value="true" style="padding: 0.25em;"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i></button>. And it posts 'remove' => ''